# How to ROUND up digit after decimal point

Tags: sql, oracle

Recently I found a problem in my SQL code, which provides me with bad output (because of my fault of course).
So the problem is that I want to specifically ROUND UP after decimal point, specifically
I want 4.802 to become 4.9, similarly 5.210 to become 5.3

ROUND itself is not sufficient in this case

I want 4.802 to become 4.9, similarly 5.210 to become 5.3

Thanks much

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
ROUND( number [, decimal_places] )
```

similar functions are

```
CEIL( number )
```

and

```
FLOOR( number )
```

Comment: Maybe fill in too `ROUND(4.802 + 0.05, 1)`

Comment: I have already figured it out, but thanks :) my solution uses CEIL(4.802*10)/10